# Parse google trends (csv file)

Tags: php, curl, cron

I´m trying to get google trends data by parsing this csv file:

```
https://trends.google.com/trends/api/widgetdata/comparedgeo/csv?req={'geo':{'country':'US'},'comparisonItem':[{'time':'2017-10-06 2018-10-06','complexKeywordsRestriction':{'keyword':[{'type':'BROAD','value':'travel'}]}}],'resolution':'REGION','locale':'de','requestOptions':{'property':'','backend':'IZG','category':0}}&token=APP6_UEAAAAAW7o-Y1_D87AoOXJJqulrVGiPmc3Cz6_Z&tz=-120
```

I tried it with php and curl, doesn´t work. I get an error page of google. Telling me "Bad Request". Alternatively I could download it with a cronjob but also this doesn´t work for me. Any chance to get/download this file?

```
 <?php


ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);


$ch = curl_init(); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://trends.google.com/trends/api/widgetdata/comparedgeo/csv?req={'geo':{'country':'US'},'comparisonItem':[{'time':'2017-10-06 2018-10-06','complexKeywordsRestriction':{'keyword':[{'type':'BROAD','value':'travel'}]}}],'resolution':'REGION','locale':'de','requestOptions':{'property':'','backend':'IZG','category':0}}&token=APP6_UEAAAAAW7o-Y1_D87AoOXJJqulrVGiPmc3Cz6_Z&tz=-120"); 
$agent= 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)'; 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 15); //time out of 15 seconds
$output = curl_exec($ch); 



curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Comment: You're not parsing anything, you are trying to download something. BTW: You're also not checking for any error that could give you a hint what you're doing wrong. That said, what is the relevant relation to `cron`?

Comment: don´t I have to GET something first before parsing?

Comment: Yes, true. Reread your question though, you write "parse google trends". No mentioning of downloading there, even though that rather seems to be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because there's a literal space in your URL. Here's a working example:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);


$ch = curl_init(); 

$url = "https://trends.google.com/trends/api/widgetdata/comparedgeo/csv?req={'geo':{'country':'US'},'comparisonItem':[{'time':'2017-10-06 2018-10-06','complexKeywordsRestriction':{'keyword':[{'type':'BROAD','value':'travel'}]}}],'resolution':'REGION','locale':'de','requestOptions':{'property':'','backend':'IZG','category':0}}&token=APP6_UEAAAAAW7o-Y1_D87AoOXJJqulrVGiPmc3Cz6_Z&tz=-120";
$url = str_replace(" ", '%20', $url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
$agent= 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)'; 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 15); //time out of 15 seconds
$output = curl_exec($ch); 



curl_close($ch);

print_r($output);

?>
```

But you really don't need to use CURL here:

```
<?php

$url = "https://trends.google.com/trends/api/widgetdata/comparedgeo/csv?req={'geo':{'country':'US'},'comparisonItem':[{'time':'2017-10-06 2018-10-06','complexKeywordsRestriction':{'keyword':[{'type':'BROAD','value':'travel'}]}}],'resolution':'REGION','locale':'de','requestOptions':{'property':'','backend':'IZG','category':0}}&token=APP6_UEAAAAAW7o-Y1_D87AoOXJJqulrVGiPmc3Cz6_Z&tz=-120";

$url = str_replace(" ", '%20', $url);

$result = file_get_contents($url);

print_r($result);

?>
```